# Can i grow bacteria on potato dextrose agar?

Tags: microbiology

I was wondering if potato dextrose agar was a suitable environment for bacteria. Does it have all the requirements bacteria need or is it limited? Specifically:
*Escherichia coli*,
*Staphylococcus aureus*,
*Enterococcus faecium*, 
*Pseudomonas aeruginosa*.

Comment: We need to know which bacteria you want to grow in order to answer you

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifics about the bacteria I question this will be kept vague.

Generally speaking though, yes, some bacterias can be cultured using a PDA plate. The plate contains potato starch agar and dextrose. Sometimes Tartaric acid is added to stop unwanted bacterial colonies from forming, which again highlights how possible it is for them to form on the plate. The mechanism of action of the Tartaric acid is to lower the pH, out of the physiological range of most bacteria.